# Using an AJAX call to call Transport for London Open API air quality data?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to parse air quality data using the Transport for London (TFL) open API. I have gotten the API working for bus lines and routes, using the following code

```
        function getTimes(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api-ganges.tfl.gov.uk/Line/64/Arrivals?app_id=XXXXX&app_key=XXXXX',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(data){
                    $("#times").html("");

                    // declare a variable called sorted
                    var sorted = data.sort(function(a,b){
                        if (a.timeToStation > b.timeToStation){
                            return 1;
                        }
                        if (a.timeToStation < b.timeToStation){
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return 0;
                    });
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        var line = value.lineName;
                        var stopName = value.stationName;
                        var destination = value.destinationName;
                        var time = value.timeToStation;
                        time = parseInt(time/60);
                        time < 1 ? time = "due" : time = time+" min";
                        $("#times").append(line+" "+stopName+"-"+destination+" "+time+"<br>");


                    });
                }
            });

        }
```

And this is called on a button press and returns a list of bus routes and times until they arrive.

I have tried using this code below so far:

```
        function getAirQuality(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api-ganges.tfl.gov.uk/AirQuality?app_id=XXXXX&app_key=XXXXX',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(data){


                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        console.log(data)
                        var array = [];
                        var summary = value;




                        //var text = value.currentForecast;

                        $("#air").append(summary);


                    });
                }
            });

        }
```

And I can only get it to print "value"
If i console.log(data) I find that there is an object called currentForecast, but if I add that into my code, it does not show anything when the button is pressed.

The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="times">Times</div>
<button onclick="getTimes();">Click to get times</button>
<div id="air">Air Quality forecast summary:</div>
<button onclick="getAirQuality();">Click to get Air Quality</button>
<script>





        function getTimes(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api-ganges.tfl.gov.uk/Line/64/Arrivals?app_id=XXXXX&app_key=XXXXX',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(data){
                    $("#times").html("");

                    // declare a variable called sorted
                    var sorted = data.sort(function(a,b){
                        if (a.timeToStation > b.timeToStation){
                            return 1;
                        }
                        if (a.timeToStation < b.timeToStation){
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return 0;
                    });
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        var line = value.lineName;
                        var stopName = value.stationName;
                        var destination = value.destinationName;
                        var time = value.timeToStation;
                        time = parseInt(time/60);
                        time < 1 ? time = "due" : time = time+" min";
                        $("#times").append(line+" "+stopName+"-"+destination+" "+time+"<br>");


                    });
                }
            });

        }



        function getAirQuality(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api-ganges.tfl.gov.uk/AirQuality?app_id=XXXXX&app_key=XXXXX',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(data){


                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        console.log(data)
                        var array = [];
                        var summary = value;




                        //var text = value.currentForecast;

                        $("#air").append(summary);


                    });
                }
            });

        }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting the get Air Quality button to show my what is inside the object at least, as a starter

Comment: You have two URLs - which one is causing the problem/both?  Can you provide an example output as they both require an app id/key which you've (rightly) not included.  It could be that it's not correctly formatted json.

Comment: The bottom one, for getAirQuality, the object I am trying to get returns a json formatted object when I console.log(data)

Comment: An example output would be: {
  "$id": "1",
  "$type": "tfl data",
  "updatePeriod": "hourly",
  "updateFrequency": "1",
  "forecastURL": "http://londonair.org.uk/forecast",
  "disclaimerText": "disc",
  "currentForecast": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CurrentForecast, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "forecastType": "Current",
      "forecastID": "22462",
      "forecastBand": "Low",
      "forecastSummary": "summary",
          "forecastText": "sample text"
    },
   

  ]
} but it has valid data.

Comment: Getting the data is not the issue, pointing the code to currentForecast in the object seems to be the main issue.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: If that's an example output, then it's not an array and the first thing you do is treat it as an array `$.each(data` - try `console.log(data.currentForecast)`

Comment: Alternatively, see what you get with: `$.each(data, function(key, value) { console.log(key, value); });`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>   <!--  HERE IS THE ANSWER YOU ARE LOOKING FOR  -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Air Qualily</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="air">Air Quality forecast summary:</div>
<button onclick="getAirQuality();">Click to get Air Quality</button>
<script>

function getAirQuality(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api-ganges.tfl.gov.uk/AirQuality',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data){

            var summary = data.currentForecast[0].forecastText;
            //remove strange characters
            summary = summary.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');  
            summary = summary.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
 
            console.log(summary);

            $("#air").append(summary);            
        }
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The data you want can be buried deep in the JSON structure. If you make use of a chrome extension called JSONview you can rt-click over a value in the JSON and get the path to that bit of data.  This tool will help you access it.